# Is there a way to easily count rows in a table on the report page in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

After creating a table on the report tab I need to count the number of rows that are in the table, this seems SUPER easy, right?  I agree, it should be.

Well, if I add in another field into the "values" list and try to make this a "count" or "count (distinct)" type then the table's filters seem to be affected and I get different information in the table than what I had seen previously.  WEIRD.

So, I need a way to count the number of rows in a table on the report tab without adding in another column to the table.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Can provide more information if needed!

Comment: Create a measure: My Count = COUNTROWS ( TableName). Add it the the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CreatedCounts = 
CALCULATE(COUNT('Bugs - All history by month'[Work Item Id]),
DATESBETWEEN('Bugs - All history by month'[Created Date],
MIN('Bugs - All history by month (2)'[Iteration Start Date]),
MAX('Bugs - All history by month (2)'[Iteration End Date])))
```

This is what I came up with, and it works exactly as I want from what I can tell, but I don't really 100% understand WHY it works, so if anyone can provide an explanation (or better solution!) please let me know, thanks!